# was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, css, jdocument

The files are loaded as so:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('media/breezingforms/slider-radio/slider-radio/slider-radio.js');
$document->addStyleSheet('media/breezingforms/slider-radio/slider-radio/slider-radio.css');
```

Some work that way, but these two in particular don't.  Are there any variables I can add to my `addStyleSheet` or `addScript` to make it work?

Comment: Is this a matter of `rel="stylesheet"` getting in the way?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/44657829/2943403 Are the paths correct? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45528748/2943403 (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/274602)

Comment: Yes it could be, but how do you remove that when using `addStyleSheet`?

Comment: I don't know.  Can you, first, confirm that the files DO exist at the path supplied? Is your accepted answer perhaps too hasty? Did it resolve your issue or merely suggest how to continue working toward a resolution? Will it resolve future researchers' issues?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes too hasty, the problem still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely means that you are adding non-existing assets. Their links generate a 404 page which is why you're getting the `text/html` MIME type instead of respective types for CSS/JS files.

Comment: This is my suspicion as well.

Comment: It seems to me that all of the mismatched items are missing .css from the end of the file name.

Comment: Yup, a typo.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sharky Thank you for correcting me. In this case you were right. Take care. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error comes from what is known as CSP (Content Security Policy) configured on your web server. If you don't know what it is. Please contact your hosting provider. For any information you can read [this article on MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Take care. Hope it helps.

Comment: This will be Admin Tools then which is setting this policy I think.  Thank you.

Comment: @Eoin Glad to help. Have a nice day.